# python censor function by codeacademy

Tags: python

```
def censor(text, word):
    final_text = ''
    new_text = ''
    items = text.split()
    for i in items:
        if i == word:
            new_text = "*" * len(word)
            final_text.join(new_text)
        else:
            new_text = items
            final_text.join(new_text)
    return final_text

print censor("this hack is wack hack", "hack")
```

the above function is intended to censor the word "hack" with asterisks present in the text. Can I know where is the flaw in the above code. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Read the documentation on the `.join` method. It doesn't work the way you think it does.

Comment: It would be convenient to also point out what flaw you see. Is it a wrong result, or an error that interrupts computation?

Comment: 'this hack is wack hack'.replace('hack', '****') == 'this **** is wack ****'

Comment: @Darcinon More generally, `def censor(text, word): return text.replace(word, '*' * len(word))`

Comment: Indeed! And case insensitive: `def censor(text, word): return re.compile(re.escape(word), re.IGNORECASE).sub('*' * len(word), text)`

Answer (score 1):

This should be it.

```
def censor(text, word):
    final_text = ''
    new_text = ''
    items = text.split()
    for index, w in enumerate(items):  #'index' is an index of an array
        if w == word:
            new_text = "*" * len(word)
            items[index] = new_text # substituting the '*'
    final_text = ' '.join(items)    # the correct way how join works
    return final_text

print censor("this hack is wack hack", "hack")
```

The other way:

```
text = 'this hack is wack hack'
word = 'hack'
print text.replace(word, '*' * len(word))
```

The way **join()** works in python is you execute it on a join sign (e.g. ' ', '-', ',' etc), and you provide the list inside the join(list_in_here)

Simple example:

```
>>>'-'.join(['1','human','is','a','one'])
'1-human-is-a-one'
```

Comment: It would be nice to explain your solution. Specifically, point out how the OP's usage of `join()` was incorrect and what he was intending to do was substitute items in the list that match the word with asterisks. To simplify the code, the initialisation of `final_text` and `new_text` are redundant and you can also simplify the if block to `items[index] = "*" * len(word)`.

Comment: That is true, however as I understood the user who asked the question is new to python, so its better to do step by step for now, so its easier to understand the way python works. imo

Comment: But you're only dumping a solution and you expect a newcomer to python to see through your reasoning behind it? A good answer is not only useful for providing a solution that works, but also teaching why the thing the OP attempted was wrong, or why the solution is a better way of going about it.

Comment: Don't you mind to set it as resolved if it helped you to solve the issue and you satisfied with the answer :) Thnx @RamkrishnaMelgiri